# Performing assembly in Xcode sometimes produces llvm instead

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, xcode, assembly

I'm using (Product -> Perform Action -> Assemble "file") in Xcode to investigate assembler instructions. But for some unknown to me reasons it sometimes shows llvm instructions instead. It happens for both .c and .m files. Sometimes it suddenly just starts to produce llvm for the same file which produced assembler many times before. Has anyone else encountered this? Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Xcode 15.0.1